# how to set dynamic linearlayout in Relativelavout

Tags: android, android-layout

How to set two linearlayout in relativelayout dynamically with vertical orientation .And how to add controls in two linearlayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <RelativeLayout 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="horizontal" 
         android:id="@+id/yourlayout"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"

         >
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Button 1"
    ></Button>

            </LinearLayout>  



            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <Button android:id="@+id/button2" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Button 2"
    ></Button>
            </LinearLayout>

         </RelativeLayout>
```

And you can just inflate this layout where you want and parameters you want.

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whereyouwant, null);
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourlayout);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parametri = new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    parametri.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    rl.addView(v, parametri);
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whereyouwant, null);
What do u mean by (whereyouwant)

Comment: Oops, sorry, there you inflate the layout you want to display. Name the xml code like mynewlayout.xml. and then do R.layout.mynewlayout

Answer (score 0):

hi There's nothing called vertical orientation for RelativeView. Widget inside RelativeLayout are place in relative postions to eachother. So if you wnat one linearlayout to come below of another .. you need to user android:layout_below attribute for former layout.

Comment: Maybe he meant vertical orientation for the linearlayouts. Or I got him that way. Lol :)

Comment: ya i meant for vertical orientation for the linearlayouts.